# Using a service in angular 4 guards

Tags: angular-guards

Please assist with angular guards, I have the following angular Guard below :

```
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {

 private role: any;
 constructor(private router: Router, private accountService: AccountService) 
 {}

   canActivate(
      next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
      state: RouterStateSnapshot
   ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

     this.accountService.getUserRole().subscribe(res => this.role = res);
     if (this.role === 'admin') {
         return true;
     }
   return false;
 }
}
```

in the service:

```
  getUserRole(): Observable<Response> {
  const options = this.headers();
    return this.http.get(`${environment.ApiUrl}/Roles/getRole`,options)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .catch(res => Observable.throw(res.json()));
 }
```

I am trying to subscribe to the `getUserRole()` function, then assign the response to `this.role` but that is not happening, role is always `undefined`. when i do a `...subscribe(res => console.log(res))` i see the response data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wait the result of the async HTTP Request before check if can activate that route or not.

Try returning a new Observable instead:

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    return new Observable(observer => {   
        //
        this.accountService.getUserRole().subscribe(role => {
            //
            if (role === 'admin') {
                observer.next(true); // Allowing route activation
            } else {
                observer.next(false); // Denying route activation                
            }
        }, err => observer.next(false)); 
    }); 
}
```